# Close an open IFile in editor if it is deleted in Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a requirement to close an open IFile in editor if it is deleted in Project Explorer.

As I understand **IResourceChangeListener** can be used to listens to changes in project workspace but how can I get the perticular file which has been deleted.

as 
`event.getResource()` returns a IProject being changed it seems .

How can I locate the file which has been deleted and close that file in editor if its open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resource change event usually contains information about changes to all related resources. For a file change this will be the file, parent folders and the project. The `getResource` method of `IResourceChangeEvent` just returns you the top most resource that has been changed.

The `IResourceDelta` returned by `getDelta` contains the full set of resources that the resource change event covers:

```java
IResourceDelta delta = event.getDelta();
```

You can search the delta for a particular file with:

```java
IResourceDelta fileDelta = delta.findMember(file.getFullPath());
```

You can also use the `accept` method to call a 'visitor' on each resource.